# nginx + perl setup guide for windows

Tags: perl, windows-7, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I'm looking for a guide, tutorial or advices to just have an nginx webserver working on windows configured with localhost site which can run perl scripts.

I know how to do it with Apache so, please do not answer that. Already got an Apache 2.4 running aside with IIS, properly configured tu run perl-cgi scripts. I'm looking for the nginx solution.

Thanks

Comment: Same question here: Nginx + Strawberry Perl. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I was able to install nginx and perl for windows separately, but without success making them work together.

Answer (score 0):

The historical answer is to setup a proxy to apache from the nginx side.  I would personally prefer a solution based on FCGI